# Different proofs for $n ( n + 1 ) ( n + 2 ) ( n + 3 )$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, square-numbers

Different proofs that show $n ( n + 1 ) ( n + 2 ) ( n + 3 )$ cannot be the square of an integer, where n is a natural number.

Comment: Presumably, you mean for positive integers $n$, since $n=0,-1.-2,-3$ are cases.

Comment: True $n$ has to be a natural number.

Comment: For variety, the scenic route it http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1975-46.pdf

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I'm learning about strategies to solve mathematical problems.  I came across this particular problem that was used in a 1926 Hungarian contest because is used in a book as an introductory example to strategies, so it has several ways to prove this problem.  Even as the book discusses this one problem, it seems that this is a special problem, part of a bigger one, as shown by the reference above by Macavity (Erdos proof).  Roman83 brought to the table a proof and I asked him how he visualized what apparently was the crux or a hint of the key to solve the problem.  He responded.

Comment: Another thing $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+1$ is a perfect square. So it's simple.

Comment: @Dhruv it may be trivial if you already know this by hindsight.  How would you prove this?

Comment: @Roman83 has given a good proof but he has lengthened things a bit. I would have changed $(n^2 + 3n)(n^2 + 3n+2)$ into $(n^2 + 3n+1)^2 -1^2$.

Comment: Its trivial that no consecutive squares exist except $1$ and $0$.

Answer (score 19):

$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=n(n+3)(n+1)(n+2)=(n^2+3n)(n^2+3n+2)=$$
Let $n^2+3n=a$
$$=a(a+2)=a^2+2a$$
$$a^2<a^2+2a<a^2+2a+1=(a+1)^2$$
$$(n^2+3n)^2<n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)<(n^2+3n+1)^2$$

Comment: How did you visualized that $n^2+3n=a$?

Comment: If $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)=A$ and $a+d=b+c=K$, then 
$$(x+a)(x+d)(x+b)(x+c)=(x^2+(a+d)x+ad)(x^2+(b+c)x+bc)=$$
$$=(x^2+Kx+ad)(x^2+Kx+bc)$$
Then $x^2+Kx=a$

Comment: That's an elegant proof.